# PuppeteerSharp requests to localhost?

Tags: browser, puppeteer, chromium, interception, puppeteer-sharp

I am not exactly sure if that is a pure PuppeteerSharp question or if it belongs to puppeteer in general.

I setup a browser with a page and request interception. When the browser navigates to an external webpage like google I subscribed the page request event and now I get some requests to localhost to different ports.
I wrote a firewall with a whitelist on my own and I am asking myself do I have to allow those requests to localhost or not? I haven't noticed any difference. What's the difference when I blocked those or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript itself tried to make requests to localhost, I just saw it when I used a real browser. So the question is answered.